# Serve Angular 6 .NetCore project from sub folder

Tags: angular, .net-core

I've create a .Net Core Angular project using the supplied VS template (VS2017). I immediately updated to Angular 6. The project is running perfectly when served from the root (IIS fronting Kestrel), however we have a requirement to run the project from a /ui folder on the server (Mysite.com/ui). I have the .net core project files (dlls, .config, etc) in the root and the angular file in a /ui folder. This setup looks right to  me.
I have tried a number of options/combinations to make this work but as yet no luck. Things I have tried:

In StartUp.cs -> ConfigureServices I have:

```
// In production, the Angular files will be served from this directory
services.AddSpaStaticFiles(c=> {c.RootPath = "ui"; });
```

Everything else in StartUp.cs is as standard from the template.

In angular.json I have:

```
"baseHref" : "/ui/"
```

I have also tried:

```
 "deployUrl": "/ui/"
```

This serves the index page, but loading in the js files produces an unexpected character < error and the contents of these js files (main, pollyfill, etc) is the contents of the index.html. Hope that bit makes sense.

Any suggestions as to what to try next?
Any further details please just ask

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked this article? https://neelbhatt.com/2018/06/02/create-an-application-with-angular-6-and-net-core-step-by-step-guide/comment-page-1/

Comment: Yes I’ve seen that article. This setup works for me if I follow it. However it’s not quite what I want as that article doesn’t have the site responding to /ui  (mysite.com/ui)